# Problems with CSS hover

Tags: css, reactjs

this my code

**CSS**

```
.Navigation-signIn {
  background-color: #c8db5a;
}

.Navigation-signIn։hover {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

**JSX**

```
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <NavLink className={"Navigation-signIn"} to={"/"}>
        <span>{"S"}</span>
        <span>{"ign In"}</span>
      </NavLink>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

[CodeSandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-pasteur-mbsf2?file=/src/styles.css:0-110)

When I want to use `։hover` in my code it doesn't work. What is the reason?

Comment: (It appears to be this one: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D6%89)

Comment: `։` !== `:`. `'։'.codePointAt(0) === 1417;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The colon you used in your CSS isn't standard. You can see it in [the demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-pasteur-mbsf2?file=/src/styles.css), if not here. Compare the one on `:hover` to the one on the line below.

Answer (score 0):

Did you happen to copy your code from somewhere? When I commented out and wrote it again it works. Additionally, it's better to write your css styling code like the following in the future:

```css
/* a.signIn:link {
  background-color: #c8db5a;
}

a.signIn։hover {
  background-color: black;
} */

a.signIn:link {
  text-decoration: none;
}

a.signIn:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: red;
  background: white;
}
```

Also using JSX, you don't need {} when you are just writing a text className or context. {} should be used only if you are adding something written in JS or other JSX.